# Get file names separated c - linux

Tags: c, file, input, args

In C-linux - how can I get an input of unknown number of file names separated by space and save each file name separately as a string?
and another question - a friend told me about "args" as a solution for some problems with unknown number of something. so my question is - what is this "args" he talk about??

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know `main()`'s  signature in c? And you should take care of white spaces embeded in the file names, have you thought about that?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You'll find anything you need in this [awesome link](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/134479?hl=en)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In c the `main()` function can take two parameters the first one being the number of arguments and the second an array with the arguments, so you wont need to store each string anywhere you can use this array for the lifetime of the program.

Here is an example of you to print these arguements to the standard output

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int index;
    for (index = 1 ; index < argc ; ++index)
        printf("Argument %d -> %s\n", index, argv[index]);
    return 0;
}
```

as you can see, the number of arguments is `argc`, the first argument if the program was invoked from the shell will be the program name, the next arguments are the arguments passed to the program.

Suppose you complied the program like this

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O0 -g3 source.c -o program
```

then you can invoke the program this way

```
./program FileName1 "A file name with spaces embeded" another_file
```

the output would be

```
Argument 1 -> FileName1
Argument 2 -> A file name with spaces embeded
Argument 3 -> another_file
```

usually `argv[0]` is the program name, but you can't guarantee that, if the program is invoked from a shell, it's pretty safe to assume that though.

Comment: The program does not match the output.  "Argument %d -> " seems to be missing.

Comment: @WilliamPursell yes i was reading the answer again to see if it was complete and noticed that....

Answer (score 0):

Your program will (or should) have a `main` function like this:

```
int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
   ...
}
```

`argc` tells you how many arguments your program is passed, and `argv` is an array of them. IE the arguments are in `argv[0]` ... `argv[argc-1]`.

Beware that `argv[0]` is actually the name of the program, rather than the first additional supplied argument, which is in `argv[1]`.

Comment: _Beware that `argv[0]` is actually the name of the program_, not necessarily, but almost always true.

Comment: @iharob indeed. But it's never the first passed parameter.